# SoapUI with Groovy Script reading values

Tags: groovy, soapui

SoapUI with Groovy 
I am using SoapUI pro and groovy script. I am reading the customers record from request into the following,

```
def CustRec = context.expand('${GetProductPriceOffer#Request#/tem:request[1]/quot:Customers[1]}' )
```

the value in CustRec is,

```
<quot:Customers>
<quot:Person>
<quot:CustomerType>PRIMARY</quot:CustomerType>
<quot:Sequence>0</quot:Sequence>
</quot:Person>
<quot:Person>
<quot:CustomerType>ADULT</quot:CustomerType>
<quot:Sequence>1</quot:Sequence>
</quot:Person>
</quot:Customers>
```

Now I want to count the total number of Person objects in Customers (i.e. answer is 2 in this scenario).  I tried with while loop but it did not work for me. 
Can anyone tell how can I achieve using the loops?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show the code for your while loop.

Comment: Your groovy snippet specifies to only get one record from the Customers.  Is that the snippet you're using before the loop, or did you modify it?

Comment: I did not modify anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count all the occurrences of `<Person>` inside `<Customers>` you can use [`count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/count) xpath function as follows:

```
def numPersons =
context.expand('${GetProductPriceOffer#Request#count(//*:Customers/*:Person)}')
```

Another possibility is to use [`XmlSlurper`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html) instead of using xpath, with it you can count the occurrences of `<Person>`, but if you need to do more operations you can manipulate the Xml in a easy way. To count the `<Person>` you can use the follow approach:

```
def custRec = context.expand('${GetProductPriceOffer#Request}')
// parse the request
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(custRec)
// find all elements in xml which tag name it's Person
// and return the list
def persons = xml.depthFirst().findAll { it.name() == 'Person' }
// here you've the number of persons
log.info persons.size()
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hi albciff,

Thank you so much for your help.Both solutions worked for me.
I am new to programmimg and learning right now. Can you please give some suggestions ?
Where can i find documentation about SoapUI Groovy scripting ?

Srini

Comment: @Sirini You can check the official groovy language page documentation at http://www.groovy-lang.org/documentation.html . Additionally you can check some SOAPUI documentation on how to achieve specific SOAPUI things using groovy, [here](http://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/tips---tricks.html) there is an example on how to access request,response, getProperties on different tests levels. Hope this helps `:)`

Comment: @Sirni also If my answers solve your problem please consider to [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) `:)`